# Read a text from string then compare on list of xml files using c#

Tags: c#

I have a console application which will read all the .txt and .xml files on a directory. Inside the txt file, are list of xml files. My application must read every txt file inside then check if the xml files listed inside the txt files are available on that directory.

Files inside the directory example:

```
123_Client_01022013_Summary.txt
123_Client_01022013_File1.xml
123_Client_01022013_File2.xml
```

Inside the 123_Client_01022013_Summary.txt is:

```
123_Client_01022013_File1.xml
123_Client_01022013_File2.xml
```

And this is my code:

```
var directorypath = @"C:\";
string line;

List<String> txtlist = Directory.GetFiles(directorypath, "*.txt").ToList();
List<String> xmllist = Directory.GetFiles(directorypath, "*.xml").ToList();

foreach (var txt in txtlist)
{
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(txt);

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        foreach (var xml in xmlist)
        {
            FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(xml);

            if (fileinfo.Name == line)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working: Checking the txt inside the txt file, then every line it will check if that xml is existing on the directory.

Is there any way I can do this a bit less expensive? I know my logic seems right but i'm not sure if this is the best way I can do it. Any advise would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the performance bad? If not, don't worry about it - The code is clear, it's easy to understand what it is doing. An optimisation would probably make it harder to understand. That being said, it may be more efficient to use the static `File.Exists(string path)` instead of creating a `FileInfo` object in each loop. Go ahead and measure both methods, I believe you will find that the difference is negligible.

Comment: I'm not sure if the performance is bad but I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @Treb I'm kinda confused. Why should I replace the `FileInfo` with `File.Exists`?

Comment: `FileInfo` requires the creation of an object for every single xml, each time you process a text file. `File.Exists`is a static method, which doesn't require the overhead of object creation. You most likely will need to process a directory with a few thousand files in in, in order to see the difference, though.

Comment: @Treb And how should I use the `File.Exists`? By passing xml? Or the txt inside the txtfile?

Comment: `File.Exists(@"C:\YourDirectory\YourFile.xml")` You can also use a relative path, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq you can do something like that:

```
string[] txtList =
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(directorypath, "*.txt")
             .SelectMany(f => File.ReadAllLines(f))
             .ToArray();

string[] xmlList =
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(directorypath, "*.xml")
             .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f))
             .ToArray();

// XML files that are listed in .txt files but are not present in the directory
var missingXmlFiles = txtList.Except(xmlList);

// XML files that are present in the directory but not listed in .txt files
var extraXmlFiles = xmlList.Except(txtList);
```

Comment: Perhaps use HashSet<string> instead of string[] but IO is probably going to be the bottleneck. (+1)

Comment: Will this still work if I have more than one txt file inside the directory?

Comment: @JohanLarsson, I don't think HashSet is going to change anything, because Except already uses it internally (or something similar to it). I used ToArray just to materialize the results and avoid accessing the file system twice.

Comment: @Gerald, yes; txtList will contain all lines of all text files in the directory

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should read first just the txt files and get the list of valid xml files (so not create the xmllist at the beginning with the GetFiles), then separately open them. So you will not have the a O2 complexity (two nested foreach).

Comment: Thus, you also don't have to create a `FileInfo` object, but just call `File.Exists(xmlFilename)`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
        var directorypath = @"C:\";

        List<String> txtlist = Directory.GetFiles(directorypath, "*.txt").ToList();

        foreach (var textFile in txtlist)
        {
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(textFile))
            {
                var xmlFiles = file.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var xmlFilesThatDontExsit = xmlFiles.Where(x => !System.IO.File.Exists(x));
                //Do what you want with the files that dont exist
            }
        }
```

Of course this assumes that the only files in the Text file are XML files (as that is not checked)

Answer (score 0):

Upon considering one of the comments, I ended up not getting the list of xml files but the xml filenames only.

```
 List<String> txtlist = Directory.GetFiles(directorypath, "*.txt").ToList();
 List<String> xmllist = Directory.GetFiles(directorypath, "*.xml").Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToList();


 foreach (var txt in txtlist)
 {
     StreamReader file = new StreamReader(txt);

     while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         foreach (var xml in xmlist)
         {
             if (xml == line)
             {
             break;
             }
         }
    }
 }
```

So now i'm not creating an object of `FileInfo` while doing a foreach loop.